# setTimeout Cascading Animations with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add a class to a series of spans using setTimeout() such that the class is added in cascading fashion, creating a visual progression rather than having them all set at once. I've tried so many different ways.

Here's a codepen...
http://codepen.io/geirman/pen/nDhpd

The codepen tries to mimic a working example I've found here...
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration

The problem is that I can't seem to delay the addClass successively, so it happens all at once. Here's the current code.

```
 /* The Problem Code
 ********************/

 var span$ = $("span");
 var index = 0;
 var factor = 500;

 function colorSpans(){
   for(var i = 0; i < span$.length; i++){
     setTimeout(function(){
       animate();
     }, factor*index);
   }
   index = 0; 
 }

 function animate(){  
   span$[index++].className = "lg"; 
 }

 colorSpans();
```

One more thing, I'd love to do this sans jQuery, but will accept a jQuery solution as well.

Comment: Just a note since you mentioned jQuery, this would likely not be easier to do even with jQuery, as the `delay()` function you were probably thinking of only works on the jQuery animations, it doesn't work as a `sleep()`. (Meaning it wouldn't work on your `animate()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code, it looks like the very first call to `animate` will execute immediately, after which `index` will be `1`. But the loop is likely to finish executing before the second timeout-handler is called (i.e., the loop won't take 500ms to execute). So this means that the remaining spans will appear instantaneously since the value of `index` will not be updated.

Something like this should work:

```
function colorSpans() {
    for(var i = 0; i < span$.length; i++) {
       (function(i) {
           setTimeout(function() {
               animate(i);
           }, factor * i);
       })(i); //force a new scope so that the "i" passed to animate()
              //is the value of "i" at that current iteration and not
              //the value of "i" when the loop is done executing.
    }
}

function animate(i) {
    span$[i].className = "lg";
}
```

The above code is also preferable because you're not using a global variable to maintain state between `colorSpans` and `animate` (i.e., we're not using `index`).

But you can make additional improvements by using `setInterval` instead:

```
var i = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    if(i < span$.length) {
        animate(i);
        i++;
    } else {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 500)
```

I think this is cleaner than the `setTimeout` approach.

Check out the updated codepens:

- [`setTimeout` approach](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tqLDe)
- [`setInterval` approach](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qDtLH)

Comment: Thank you Vivin! I hadn't thought about the fact that index wouldn't actually increment before the 500ms timeout. Good call!